# Is Sha3 an alias for keccak256?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA18 {

address public owner;

function CA18 () {
    owner = msg.sender;
}



mapping(address=>uint16) public balances;

function getBalance() view returns (uint16, bytes32) {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    uint16 mybalance = 1000;
    bytes32 c = keccak256(owner);
    return (mybalance, c);
}



}

> con.getBalance()
[1000, "0x0679d661b585d1b4f0c3fd18f943f19e7fa9777fe23cb96b94f469c20d6f0bd5"]
> web3.sha3(eth.coinbase)
"0x3ba2c5fae04972f5960bd8d1b7f098bf7d4c844da67accd23da00f62e4910fc0"
> con.owner()
"0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305"
> web3.sha3(con.owner())
"0x3ba2c5fae04972f5960bd8d1b7f098bf7d4c844da67accd23da00f62e4910fc0"
```

Web3.sha is not the same as keccak256(owner).

The [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html) state -

```
sha3(...) returns (bytes32):
alias to keccak256
```

The outputs show sha3 to be different keccak256. Should they be the same?

(con is the contract instance.)

I just added sha3 for the owner and here is the output -

```
> con.getBalance()
[1000, "0x0679d661b585d1b4f0c3fd18f943f19e7fa9777fe23cb96b94f469c20d6f0bd5", "0x0679d661b585d1b4f0c3fd18f943f19e7fa9777fe23cb96b94f469c20d6f0bd5"]

function getBalance() view returns (uint16, bytes32, bytes32) {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    uint16 mybalance = 1000;
    bytes32 c = keccak256(owner);
    bytes32 d = sha3(owner);
    return (mybalance, c, d);
}
```

Hence the difference is due to web3 and solidity. Has anyone any explanation about this since `sha3` is used in the addressing algorithms for storage and they work, and they are also based on `keccak256`.

Comment: This is related to input types I just saw.

Comment: Just to clarify about the docs... the docs you pointed to were for Solidity. In Solidity, `sha3` and `keccak256` should be exactly the same. Comparing to `web3.js`'s `sha3`, though, will reveal a number of differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> web3.sha3(con.owner(),  {encoding:"hex"})
"0x0679d661b585d1b4f0c3fd18f943f19e7fa9777fe23cb96b94f469c20d6f0bd5"
```